# Error executing sql statement when using java expression in ireport

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I'm using iReport for my report development.

I have 2 parameters which is the 1st parameter (companyName) is embedded into 2nd parameter(pCompanyName). I'm also filtering the parameter using 2 options. If the parameter is null, it will print out "" or blank, else it will print the query. Please refer to parameter section below. When using groovy language, it will print out the report.

The problem is after change the language from groovy to java expression the report print out the error. Below is the error. Someone here please help.. Desperate.

> Error filling print... Error executing SQL statement for : laporan_quota
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : laporan_quota
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:240)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1114)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:691)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1314)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:931)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:873)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:87)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:287)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:760)
>       at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:233)

**Sql**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
b.company_name company_name,
a.app_id permit_id,
b.quota_year,
b.app_id app_id,
g.descr ap_category,
h.descr ap_subcategory,
a.tariff_code hs_code,
h.descr model,
a.product_desc goods_description,
a.quantity quantity,
a.price_tot total_cost,
a.permit_no permit_no,
a.license_id license_no,
a.approved_date approve_date,
a.origin_country origin_country,
a.cnor_addr3 consignor_country,
a.branch_id miti_branch,
c.descr permit_status,
a.port_discharge port_name,
a.effect_date effective_date,
a.expiry_date expiry_date
FROM PERMIT_APP a, MT_PERMIT_APP_MASTER b, MT_REF_PERMIT_STATUS c, MT_QUOTA d, MT_QUOTA_APP e, MT_AP_TYPE f, MT_AP_CATEGORY g,
MT_AP_SUBCATEGORY h, MT_AP_TYPE_OPTION i
WHERE
a.master_app_id = b.app_id
AND b.quota_id = d.quota_id
AND d.quota_id = e.quota_id
AND f.ap_type_code = g.ap_type_code
AND g.ap_category_code = h.ap_category_code
AND h.ap_subcategory_code = b.ap_subcategory_code
AND f.ap_type_code = i.ap_type_code
AND a.status_code = c.status_code
AND c.status_code in ('102','301')
AND i.option_type = 'QUOTA'
$P!{pCompanyName}
```

**Parameters**

1) $P{companyName}

2) $P!{pCompanyName}

```
($P{companyName}.isEmpty() ? "" : " AND b.company_name = 'JA' ")
```

Comment: Is `$P!{pCompanyName}` part of the query?

Comment: Yes sir.. If it not null it will print the query. If null the query wont show or blank

Comment: You probably would need to place that elsewhere, because that is not part of a valid SQL query and that's what the error message is saying `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: Oh i see . In the case i must find the other way to do it. Hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, finally i got the solution correspondent to my question above.

It is because i don't put bracket inside if else code, that's why the error said sql statement error but i think it is not sql statement error, it syntax error :

**Solution**

Change this : ( $P{companyName}.isEmpty( ) ? "" : " AND b.company_name = 'JA' ")

To this : ( ($P{companyName}.isEmpty( ) ) ? "" : " AND b.company_name = 'JA' ")